# sql order by datetime and then by string

Tags: sql

I have a varchar column that I have datetime values and now string values.  I need to order by the datetime value and list all the string values at the bottom.  I have the following for the datetime:

```
ORDER BY CAST(q2.[Due Date] AS DATETIME)
```

But my results have the value "On Hold" throughout my results. I need the "On Hold" to be on the bottom of the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the only non-date value is 'On Hold', then this should work in most SQL engines:

```
order by (case when q2.[Due Date] = 'On Hold' then 0 else 1 end) desc,
         (case when q2.[Due Date] <> 'On Hold' then cast(q2.[Due Date] as datetime) end)
```

I would recommend, though, that if you are storing dates as strings, then use the format 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS'.  This will allow you to sort them without having to do a conversion.

If they are in this format, you could use something like:

```
order by (case when left([Due Date], 1) between '0' and '9' then 0 else 1 end),
         [Due Date]
```

(Just ordering by [Due Date] would work in most cases, since numbers sort before letters.  However, an arbitrary string could start with other non-alpha characters.)

Comment: except I'd change the test for one value to isdate(), allowing the string value to pass through, returning null for date values

Comment: @Beth . . . I said this would work on most SQL engines.  `isDate` is specific to SQL Server and Sybase.

Comment: I do have one more question @GordonLinoff. The 2nd suggestion above does work great but I do have the following that now isn't functioning correctly: SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY q2.[Due Date]) AS "Count", My On Hold records keep their row count so it is out of order now.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what your platform is, but in SQL Server you could just write:

```
SELECT q2.[Due Date]
FROM yourTable q2
ORDER BY ISDATE(q2.[Due Date]) DESC;
```

Comment: This one didnt work.  I still had my On Holds mixed in with my dates. Thank you though